# How to re-install windows without breaking my eOS

Tags: release-loki, dual-boot, grub, microsoft-windows

I would like to install Windows 10 in my second partition, but I don't want to break my ElementaryOS install.

I have all ready break my windows install (yesterday) so I don't want to make mistakes.

Thank.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows installation process generally does mess with Grub, the Linux bootloader. One way to prevent such issues is to install Windows in a virtual machine such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92874/how-do-i-install-windows-7-alongside-a-pre-existing-ubuntu-installation#92877) has more information on how to install Windows and then get your Linux setup working again.

If you've already backed up your data, the simplest option might be to do a clean install of Windows, replacing elementary, then install elementary alongside Windows. This probably sounds like extra work, but in general it's easier to install Linux onto a Windows machine than it is to install Windows onto a Linux machine.

For more information, see [Ubuntu's Windows Dual Boot guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).